For every instance if "A" in Column1, create a new column with all values associated with "A" from Column2
Here is an example data frame:
df <- data.frame(Key = c(rep("A", 2), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 3), rep("D", 2)),
                 DataID = round(runif(11, min = 400, max = 500), digits = 0))




Key
DataID




A
493


A
475


B
445


B
427


B
420


C
429


C
464


C
459


D
438


D
490



Problem
I need to create a new column "Duplicates" that contains all the values in "DataID" associated with the corresponding value in "Key", except for the "DataID" in that row.
Desired Output



Key
DataID
Duplicates




A
493
475


A
475
493


B
445
427, 420


B
427
445, 420


B
420
445, 427


C
429
464, 459


C
464
429, 459


C
459
429, 464


D
438
490


D
490
438



I got close using the bit of code below, but I need to exclude the value the corresponds with the DataID in the same row.
library(tidyverse)

lapply(split(df, df$Key), function(x) {
  
    x %>% 
    mutate(Test2 = paste0(across(DataID)))
    
})

Output



Key
DataID
Duplicates




B
459
c(459, 401, 489, 467)


B
401
c(459, 401, 489, 467)


B
489
c(459, 401, 489, 467)


B
467
c(459, 401, 489, 467)




When using randomly generated values it is helpful to add set.seed() to your post so that it is easier to reproduce identical results.

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df |>
  mutate(duplicates = list(DataID), .by = Key) |>
  mutate(duplicates = map2(DataID, duplicates, \(x, y) y[y != x]))

From your desired output I am not sure what type of column you expect duplicates to be (string perhaps?). Just an FYI, this outputs a list-column but the values are easily concatenated if you prefer string.
Output
   Key DataID duplicates
1    A    493        475
2    A    475        493
3    B    445   427, 420
4    B    427   445, 420
5    B    420   445, 427
6    C    429   464, 459
7    C    464   429, 459
8    C    459   429, 464
9    D    438        490
10   D    490        438


This is perfect, thank you!

How could I concatenate the values in the column if I wanted to in the future?

paste0(y[y != x], collapse ",") and use map2_chr instead.

Could also use setdiff in the map function on the last line if that's a little more reader friendly. I.e. mutate(duplicates = map2( duplicates,DataID, setdiff)) (note duplicates, DataID are swapped order)

A fuzzyjoin solution:
library(fuzzyjoin); library(dlpyr)

fuzzy_join(df, df, by = c("Key", "DataID"), 
     match_fun=list(`==`, `!=`)) |>
  summarise(Duplicates=paste(DataID.y, collapse=", "), 
    .by=c(Key.x, DataID.x))


# A tibble: 10 x 3
   Key.x DataID.x Duplicates
   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>     
 1 A          493 475       
 2 A          475 493       
 3 B          445 427, 420  
 4 B          427 445, 420  
 5 B          420 445, 427  
 6 C          429 464, 459  
 7 C          464 429, 459  
 8 C          459 429, 464  
 9 D          438 490       
10 D          490 438


Data:
df <- structure(list(Key = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"D", "D"), DataID = c(493, 475, 445, 427, 420, 429, 464, 459, 
438, 490)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


You can try
df %>%
    mutate(Duplicates = map(DataID, \(x) setdiff(DataID, x)), .by = Key)

or a faster version than setdiff
df %>%
    mutate(Duplicates = map(DataID, \(x) DataID[DataID != x]), .by = Key)

which gives
   Key DataID Duplicates
1    A    493        475
2    A    475        493
3    B    445   427, 420
4    B    427   445, 420
5    B    420   445, 427
6    C    429   464, 459
7    C    464   429, 459
8    C    459   429, 464
9    D    438        490
10   D    490        438

data
> dput(df)
structure(list(Key = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"D", "D"), DataID = c(493L, 475L, 445L, 427L, 420L, 429L, 464L,
459L, 438L, 490L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))

